# Center siblings in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is my current html

```
<body>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="side"></div>
    <div class="stuff"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Is there anyway I could snap the sibling divs to the center, as if they were in a wrapper div? That way no matter what happened they would be side by side and in the center. I unfortunately having a hard time because I have other things in the parent div.

[image: Something like this.]

Is there any way I can do this using flexbox? and without adding html?

Comment: like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZexrNp

Comment: yes like that. but I can't add a div that wraps around the content because I don't have access to change the html. The html is permanent.

Comment: Ah ok cool, sorry I re-read your post and see that now. @Michael_B has the solution then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;          /* 1 */
  align-content: space-between;     /* 2 */
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  flex: 0 0 90%;                    /* 3 */
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

.side, .stuff {
  flex-basis: 25%;                 /* 4 */
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="side">stuff</div>
<div class="stuff">side</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4h1nj8rn/1/)

Notes:

1. Flex items on every line are centered horizontally.
2. First line pins to top. Bottom line pins to bottom. Middle line is vertically centered.
3. Force one line per row.
4. Override (3), so two items can display on the second line.

Comment: so I tried this on my code, but it is not working. what does the value for display need to be? Currently mine is `display: block`

Comment: Flex properties will only work if the container is `display: flex`.